# Performance of Windows timer functions

Tags: c++, windows

I trying to call a watchdog function every 500ms using `timeSetEvent`.

Normally the watchdog is called without any problems. However when a DVD is inserted into a drive I don't get a callback for up to 8 secs as the system is busy reading the disk. Using `WindowsQueue` timer things aren't quite so bad and I get a 4 second day.

My last attempt was to set thread priority to time critical and then sleep for 500ms, but again the callback didn't occur for 8secs.

I am still running XP, but I'm not aware of changes made in later operating systems which would make this better.

I am using the DVD insertion as an example. I'd like the code to be robust to other conditions if possible.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your DVD driver is a poor example of a driver...

Comment: It's possible even in current Windows versions (8.1 at the moment) that the system locks up for short periods for various reasons. Windows does not guarantee timer intervals - if a driver locks up the system, you can't do much. There may be other reasons why your application wouldn't get callbacks for a long time even though it _thinks_ it's running.

Comment: Unfortunately it's just a standard windows driver and beyond my control.  I've tried changing thread priority and that's not really helping either

Comment: You're not using a real time OS so it makes little sense to have such strict requirements when the OS itself does not give you any guarantees.

Comment: The best result i got on windows was using TimerQueues. Still not happy with. My suggestion, don't use windows for time critical stuff.

Comment: I've got a hardware watchdog to stroke every 3 sec to prevent a reboot.  I thought that there would be sufficient headroom stroking it every 0.5s.

Comment: @jpg Read this: http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=272

Answer (score 0):

The best way we've found of getting decent timing performance from Windows is to avoid the timer functions altogether and roll your own; just sit in a tight loop, eating CPU, until the time for the next timer event comes up.  `QueryPerformanceCounter` seems to be the best way of getting fast, high-resolution time for this purpose.  Do whatever you can to give the thread that is running this loop its own CPU core that it will stick to and won't have anything else taking CPU time from.

But be warned:

- Timing is still far from perfect.  This method leaves the vast bulk of your cycles with Fairly Reasonable Timing (TM) but there will be occasional glitches, mostly in the 100s of ms but very occasionally in range of a few seconds.
- This, of course, sets something of a lower bound on your CPU utilisation.
- I still don't know how it'll perform with your DVD driver.

In general, if you need accurate timing, Windows is not the place to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this example code, meant to be used in a separate thread to run at fixed frequency, up to 400hz on Windows XP (where Sleep(1) can take up to about 2 ms). There seems to be a system wide delay when a new volume becomes ready, in this case a DVD, but a similar delay can happen if an external USB hard drive is turned on. Seems Windows XP starts scanning the new volume, locking up quite a bit of the system, and even this code example may get impacted, since it's using Sleep(1) to reduce cpu overhead. You could remove the Sleep(1) code, which would keep one of the cpu cores running at 100%, and it's still possible that inserting a DVD would even mess this up.

```
/* code for a thread to run at fixed frequency */
typedef unsigned long long UI64;        /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ    2                       /* frequency (500 ms) */

LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;               /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                      /* process frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                             /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                             /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                          /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                             /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                            /* current tick - previous */
UI64 u2ms;                              /* 2ms of ticks */
UI64 i;

    /* ... */ /* wait for some event to start thread */
    timeBeginPeriod(1);                 /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                         /* wait for it to stabilize */

    u2ms = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart)+499) / ((UI64)500);

    QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;

    for(i = 0; i < (uFreq*30); i++){
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
            if((uWait - uDelta) > u2ms)
                Sleep(1);
        }
        if(uDelta >= (uWait*2))
            dwLateStep += 1;
        uPrev += uWait;
        /* fixed frequency code goes here */
        /*  along with some type of break when done */
    }
    timeEndPeriod(1);                   /* restore period */
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the RegisterWaitForSingleObject function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?